# My Honda civic 2016 wont start after it lost its coolant

Tags: engine, honda, troubleshooting

Car lost its coolant and stopped at the exit ramp. Now I can't get it to start anymore. Refilled the coolant, and changed the oil (the old oil was still OK). But the engine crank but wont starts. Please help.
I don't want go to the dealer and get hit with another big bill.
Is there any component that may be failing like no fuel to the engine or no spark on plug. I'm planning to change the spark plug in my next step. Dash board won't show any sign of trouble !

Comment: What signs of coolant loss did the car show? Did it reach an overheating zone at a temperature gauge?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for the engine not to start after a coolant loss is a compression loss due to overheating. High temperature causes a (usually) aluminium cylinder head to bend and lose a good airtight contact with an engine block.

I'd start with a compression check, it won't cost you much.

Comment: I removed the spark plug and found plenty of coolant inside all 4 cylinders. I guess I have to take it apart and see why !